# Example 9 from Hoel, Port, Stone, Chapter 2 on Combinatorics. Distributing $n$ balls into $n$ boxes clarification

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

So I understand the problem for the most part, except for the problem statement itself.

The problem is the typical problem about distributing $n$ balls into $n$ boxes and asking what is the probability only the first box is empty, so there are a few posts on it already like the following:

[Probability: $n$ balls into $n$ holes with exactly one hole remaining empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024258/probability-n-balls-into-n-holes-with-exactly-one-hole-remaining-empty)

[Probability of $n$ balls in $n$ cells](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94061/probability-of-n-balls-in-n-cells)

I am not understanding how if we distribute $n$ balls into $n$ boxes that the total number of possible arrangements is $n^n$. Doesn't this mean that the tuple would look like this: $\{n,n,n,n,...\}$. From my understanding that means that we are doing a sampling with replacement, but I don't see how that is distributing balls into boxes. I was thinking that it should be $n!$ instead for a tuple like this $\{n,n-1,n-2,n-3,...\}$.

I am a beginner at this stuff so I think I am missing something fundamental here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no restriction on how many balls may be placed in a box, there are $n$ choices for each of the $n$ balls.  Hence, there are $n^n$ ways to distribute $n$ balls into $n$ boxes.  You would obtain $n!$ if each box could contain only one of the $n$ balls.

Comment: Wow. Okay that makes a lot of sense! Thank you!